# Can an in-app purchase add one specify an additional permission?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, android-permissions

Here's my scenario:

Currently, my app does NOT require the INTERNET permission and I would love to keep it that way. My app is a financial app where a lot of users don't want to take a chance on an app that can send their data out.

Now, I would like to have some kind of add-on that enables some on-line features, such as DropBox sync and some others which will require the INTERNET permission.

Can an app's add-on request additional permissions, and if not, can anybody suggest a reasonable way to accomplish this?

Thank you!

Comment: Both answers suggested adding a shared user ID.  I investigated that this, but it is impossible to do to an already published app as if I change the user ID, the app can no longer read its own folders.

Comment: That makes sense, and thanks for the feedback! You are also welcome to answer your own question by the way since it is important info to those coming across the question.

Comment: Thank you.  Posted this as an answer.

Comment: @A--C If the answer is correct, why not upvote it ?

Comment: @Siddharth because I didn't see the notification until now, I'm not *always* online. Speaking of which why don't you up vote it? Be a little less impatient.

Comment: @A--C I was curious. It seemed right to me. I was not mocking you :) just curious, wanted to know what you think. I will upvote it now.

Answer (score 2):

The suggested answer is to use a sharedUserId in the AndroidManifest and then create a new app with the added permission and this same user ID.  This works great for apps where the developer had foreseen this need, but for other apps, adding or changing the sharedUserId causes it to misbehave.

Here's the corresponding Google bug, please star it if you feel this should be addressed:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14074

Answer (score 1):

I had a different problem I was trying to solve and decided on add-ons also. The solution I used was to implement the Shared User Id paradigm. My add-on has the same signature, no launcher intent (which means there will be no separate icon on the users device) and a signature based security on the activity calls. This will allow you to implement the above functionality.

The issue you may have is I doubt you can get another application installed using in app purchases. You may need to sell the add-on as a separate app.

Hope this helps...